# Is it possible to manualy change a users email with firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am wondering if its possible to manually change a users email.(go to DB and change the users email on the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.  It's not even possible to change it programmatically with an update request.  You can only change the display name and and photo url.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updateEmail(java.lang.String)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The way I read it, that wouldn't be entirely programmatically.